# How to create web specific components in react-native-web?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, webrtc, react-native-web

I'm looking to create a video streaming app using react-native and roll out its web version via react-native-web so I can share the codebase. Unfortunetaly I can't wrap my head around how to properly create e.g. a `<video />` element when in the browser context.

This is what I currently have:

```
import { RTCView, /* ... some other components */ } from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const VideoViewNative = () => {
  // Some logic

  return <RTCView {/* props for RTCView */};
}

const VideoViewWeb = () => {
  return <video {/* props for web video */} />;
}


export default Platform.OS === 'web' ? VideoViewWeb : VideoViewNative;
```

While this works as expected it does not "feel" right. I think I am bypassing react-native-web here and gettings some drawbacks from that later on.

What would be the proper way to achieve what I want to achieve and why is the approach above wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try splitting the code out into separate files. React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android. or .web. extension and load the relevant platform file when required from other components.

Example:

> `VideoView.native.js`  for android and ios, also can be separate
>   platform-specific VideoView.ios.js and VideoView.android.js
>
> `VideoView.js` for others or you can also make it `VideoView.web.js`

And You can then require the component as follows:

```
import VideoView from './VideoView';
```

React Native will automatically pick up the right file based on the running platform.

Comment: Thanks :) that is useful. But can I just use regular HTML video Tags inside the web specific component or does that introduce any drawbacks?